# Find unique combinations of varying characters in a given input

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am facing a problem whereby for a given number of contracts we need to tender on all possible unique pricing scenarios. For example say there are 2 contracts A & B. We have to price up winning A only, B only or A & B, three scenarios.

If there were three contracts A, B & C this would result in 7 possible pricing scenario combinations by my count; A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC.

I worked the formula out in Javascript as follow:

```
function contractCount(numContracts) {
    return (2 ** numContracts) - 1;
}
```

I did this via trial and error and playing around in a spreadsheet. It seemed like a recursive problem but I couldn't figure out how to implement the solution recursively is there a way? Also, I was hoping somebody could explain in simple terms why my solution above works. I can understand that the answer is always going to be the number of contracts plus the accumulated possible scenarios from (number of contracts - 1) the above solution looks nothing like my mental understanding of the problem.

Comment: You can use https://www.javascripting.com/view/probability-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just to show some considerations

> only `'A'` yields
>
> ```
> A
> ```
>
> with `'A', 'B'`, you get
>
> ```
> A 
> AB         B is the value of the next call and this is added to A
> B          and used as single result
> ```
>
> with `'A', 'B', 'C'`, you get
>
> ```
> A 
> AB
> ABC
> AC
> B
> BC
> C
> ```

```js
function f(v, ...a) {
    var temp = a.length ? f(...a) : [];
    return a.length
        ? [[v], ...temp.map(a => [v, ...a]), ...temp]
        : [[v]];
}

console.log(f('A').map(a => a.join('')));
console.log(f('A', 'B').map(a => a.join('')));
console.log(f('A', 'B', 'C').map(a => a.join('')));
console.log(f('A', 'B', 'C', 'D').map(a => a.join('')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The functional style moves within you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Assume 1 = winning and 0 - not winning

Consider A and B contracts

Then all possible combinations are

A | B

0 | 0

0 | 1

1 | 0

1 | 1

But you eliminate the 0-0 combination since at least one should win. Therefore no of possible combinations are 3 = 2^2 - 1

For 3 contracts A,B,C

A | B | C

0 | 0 | 0

0 | 0 | 1

0 | 1 | 0

0 | 1 | 1

1 | 0 | 0

1 | 0 | 1

1 | 1 | 0

1 | 1 | 1

Again you we have to eliminate 0-0-0 combination. Therefore no of possible combinations are 7 = 2^3 - 1

Likewise, in your use case no of possible combinations = 2^n - 1

Comment: Cool answer, but where's the javascript? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the 0 case clarifies the -1 part of the formula but why if given 3 contracts would we even think of using 2 as the base and 3 as the exponential?

Comment: Sorry I thought you just need an explanation. Do you want a script to generate those combinations as well? If so pls let me know.

Comment: I have the basic script but a recursive script would be interesting to see. Also an understanding of why 2 is the base

Comment: If you are interested only on the number of combinations, it is just a simple straight forward calculation. There is no recursion involved.

Answer (score 0):

**in short,**
2**3 means 2x2x2 which is equals to 8 and in combinations there must be two opperands so in starting a opperand cannot be combine with himself, so we have to minus a number thats why you had to use.

```
(2 ** 3)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are just looking for the count or the actual combinations. The count is just a math problem, but returning the combinations is a little more work. Finding the combinations recursively is a classic application for [backtracking algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

```js
function groupByCount(arr, result = []) {
  const backtrack = (n, k = 0, a = []) => {
    if (k == n) return result.push(a.map((c, i) => c ? arr[i] : undefined).filter(i => i != undefined))
    k++
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      a[k - 1] = i
      backtrack(n, k, a)
    }
  }
  backtrack(arr.length)
  return result
}
let comb = groupByCount(['A', 'B', 'C'])
console.log(comb.join(' | '))

console.log(groupByCount(['A', 'B']).join(' | '))
```

This builds an boolean area representing whether each index is in the solution. Each time the array fills up it pushes a solution. I takes a little time staring at it before it clicks -- at least it does for me. Note: technically the empty set is part of the solution, so this returns that as well.

If you are just thinking about the number of combinations, here's a nice way to think about it. You can think if each of your contracts as a digit in a binary number. So in your A, B, C example, having only A might be represented as `001`, only B `010`, C `100`. When you combine them you just combine the bits so AB is `011`, AC, `101`, ABC `111`. Etc. The thing you will notice is the all the combinations are represented in a binary number with the same number of bits as the number of items you have and each combination can be counted from `001` to `111`. In other words the number of combinations will always be the same as the binary number with that many digits filled with `1`s.

With 3: `111` = 7
With 4: `1111` = 15

You can check this in javascript with `parseInt('1'.repeat(n), 2)` where `n` is the number of contract.

```js
for (let n = 1; n < 8; n++){
  let b = '1'.repeat(n)
  console.log(n + ': ' + b + ' = ' + parseInt(b, 2) + ' = ' + (2**n -1))
  }
```

Of course, that's not a very efficient way to do this because it is just another way of saying the number of combinations is 2 to the power of n -1.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was more interested in the algorithm outputting an integer representing the possible number of unique combinations rather then the actual combinations themselves. I'm also not full bottle on the map() method yet so your solution confuses me. How is it recursive? I don't see groupByCount() function calling itself?

Comment: Can't edit my last comment but I can see how that backtrack() is the recursive part

Comment: @Aza I added a bit about the intuition of counting the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Generators are great for this kind of computation

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const combinations = (...xs) =>
{ const loop = function* (comb, [x = None, ...xs])
  { if (x === None)
      return yield comb
    
    yield* loop ([...comb, x], xs)
    yield* loop (comb, xs)
  }
  return Array.from (loop ([], xs))
}

console.log (combinations ('a'))
// [ [a], [] ]

console.log (combinations ('a', 'b'))
// [ [a,b], [a], [b], [] ]

console.log (combinations ('a', 'b', 'c'))
// [ [a,b,c], [a,b], [a,c], [a], [b,c], [b], [c], [] ]
```